# Ubuntu 10.10 Screenshot of active window doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, screenshot

Ubuntu 10.10 Screenshot of full screen works. Screenshot of "selected area" works. But Screenshot of current (active) window doesn't. Nothing happens. The save screenshot window doesn't open.

Tried using Alt+Print as well as from the Panel->Accessories->Screenshot. Same result. No screenshot.

GIMP window screenshot works. But thats not the point. Why doesn't the normal way work?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 10.10, Alt+PrtScrn conflicts with Magic SysRq.  Run the following command to fix it:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.sysrq=0
```

More info can be found here: [UbuntuGuide](http://ubuntuguide.net/fix-altprint-screen-current-window-screenshot-not-working-in-ubuntu-10-10)

EDIT: An alternative is to set it to a different key combination in the Keyboard Shortcuts settings window. The option to look at is "Take a screenshot of a window"

EDIT 2: A helpful troubleshooting link was suggested in the comments below: [(AskUbuntu question)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30767/screenshot-of-active-window-doesnt-work/30774#30774)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. That does it. Didn't want to meddle with the Magic SysRq key so changed the keyboard shortcut. And now it works!

Comment: @Cocoro Feel free to accept the answer so that we both get credit for the question :-)

Comment: To use the Panel -> Accessories -> Screenshot method, one needs to increase the delay above 0 seconds and **click** on the window. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30767/ubuntu-10-10-screenshot-of-active-window-doesnt-work/30774#30774)